# Env variables configuration for multiple Heroku remotes ie. testing, staging and production

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables

I am using 3 different `git` remotes during my development namely `testing`, `staging` and `production` (on `Heroku`). I have implemented a `.env` file to handle environment variables but just want to clarify that the way I have set them up is correct.

I have implemented the following to fetch the `NODE_ENV` var and uses it accordingly to append the `.env` var strings on the page depending on the `NODE_ENV` var I set.

```
env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
envString = env;
SHEET_ID = process.env['SHEET_ID_' + envString];
```

In the documentation, they discuss default `env` vars but I am unsure if Heroku has its own `NODE_ENV` var or how it works exactly, I have been setting it myself in my local `.env` (then when pushing I change the server `NODE_ENV` var to testing, staging or production)

Is my following understanding correct?

1. The `NODE_ENV` var is located in my `.env` - is this also default env var served from the environment ie Heroku or am I correct in setting the var myself in the env file and mirroring it on the server?
2. When pushing to a remote, depending on which, is the correct way to switch the env var `NODE_ENV` var in my local `.env` to `NODE_ENV=testing`, `NODE_ENV=staging` or `NODE_ENV=production`? Then the set vars from for eg Heroku dashboard would be used instead of the local vars.
3. Is this the best way to use the same code base through each remote without having to update my local files?
4. Do environments like Heroku serve a `NODE_ENV` var by default? I console logged `process.env` but only found my local set vars.

I am trying to design things to be as maintainable and efficient as possible and when I eventually do share my code with others I would like it to be as easy to implement as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [12 factor app](https://12factor.net/) principles all configuration should happen in the environment variables.

For your app this means

- the `.env` file is merely a helper to put configuration in to the local environment for the application to work
- every app on heroku (in your case staging,testing,production) will have their own config set via the [heroku config commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars). They will end up in the local environment of your application dynos, together with whatever your addons put there (for example database credentials).